# create product attribute - file upload with certain extensions like pdf, csv etc

Tags: magento2, extensions, ecommerce-tracking, extension-attributes

I have created custom attribute type - file upload of type ravi_file in magento2.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
    $response = $observer->getEvent()->getResponse();
    $types = $response->getTypes();
    $types[] = array(
        'value' => 'ravi_file',
        'label' => __('File Upload by Ravi'),
        'hide_fields' => array(
            'is_unique',
            'is_required',
            'frontend_class',
            'is_configurable',
            '_default_value',

            'is_searchable',
            'is_visible_in_advanced_search',
            'is_filterable',
            'is_filterable_in_search',
            'is_comparable',
            'is_used_for_promo_rules',
            'position',
            'used_in_product_listing',
            'used_for_sort_by',
        )
    );
    $response->setTypes($types);
    return $this;  }
```

an attribute is created successfully. I assigned file upload attribute to default attribute set. I am getting following error on edit product.[image: Error Log]

I have created backend and frontend module by referring the https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Product-custom-attribute-file-upload/td-p/29460

## I need a way to get the attribute listed on the product page where we can upload the file for the specific product. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Used events:

1. file_upload_add FileAttributeType => for adding custom file type in dropdown of the Catalog Input Type for Store Owner
2. catalog_entity_attribute_save_before => want to call file upload functionality

Comment: How you created custom attribute via script or from backend ,if script it may be w omg with your attribute creation

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom option with the product for file upload. That's it[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKBHj.png)

Comment: It supposed to be an attribute. we can enable disable at any point of time and it will be displayed on frontend.

Comment: check this extension available in 1.9 https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/file-upload-attribute.html , I want an exactly same extension. I am trying to convert. But stuck at - to show file upload option on product edit page. refer my error log.